# JUnit Test for database exception for duplicate records

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I need test my database that, when I insert duplicate value in specific column where I have constraint, it fire exception. Can you show me how can I simulate second same call and fire exception?

here is my code, but doesn't work:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTestClass {

    @InjectMocks
    private FooService service = new FooServiceImpl();

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void myTest() {
       // init Foo object here

       service.createFoo(myFoo); // here should pass

       service.createFoo(myFoo); // here shouldn't
    }
}
```

I can't show original FooServiceImpl but the basic concept is here:

```
@Transactional
public void createFoo(Foo foo) {
   MainFoo mainFoo = new MainFoo();

   SomeObj obj1 = objService.findOne(foo.getId());

   mainFoo.setObj(obj1);

   fooRepository.save(mainFoo);
}
```

What I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: you should show FooService implementation. Note that you mock nothing here.

Comment: @davidxxx I edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if you want to test your actual database or you just need to mock the DB call.In case you just want to test your service class better mock the second statement using.

```
doThrow(ExpectedException).when(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...);
```

Also, If you are using spring, All you need to do is use `@InjectMocks` and mock the dependencies of the respected class using `@Mock`.

For consecutive calls you can use:

```
Mockito.when(repo.findOne(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(yourObject).thenThrow(EXCEPTION_OBJ)
```

Comment: I test that in my service will be fire exception from database, because in table I have unique constraint for one column. So when I call service with some object at first time it pass, but second time will throw error.

Comment: but how can I simulate second call with same parameters in mock?

Comment: How are you really executing your test cases? Do you have an embedded server in your app? Any testNg framework?

Comment: I edited my answer. So the call should return into an object and the successive call will result into an exception.

Comment: If the mocked object is recorded to throw the exception, the actual test doesn't assert that no duplication is allowed for the column as you faked this behavior with the mock. You don't want to mock the behavior to unit test.  Instead, you want to mock the dependencies preventing to unit test a component in isolation.

Comment: Agree..! I believe DS wanna test some functionality in the service class. Hence he can mock the DB calls as per the expected behavior which I got to know by the way he framed his question.
One can always have an integration test using in-memory database as suggested by you to write such a test case. Mockito has nothing to do with such a testcase

Comment: Indeed if it he wants to test a behavior that depends on the exception, it would make sense. But as he wants to assert that  `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown in the unit test, I wondered about the relevance of the unit test with Mockito here.

Answer (score 1):

> I need test my database that, when I insert duplicate value in
>   specific column where I have constraint, it fire exception.

To perform a assertion that checks that the database constraint is there and does its job, you should perform a test without mock and with an in-memory database.

The H2 database is good for that.
Before invoking the method, add in your in-memory database a recording for the Foo entity. You can do it with the EntityManager or your service, whatever.
Then invoke your method.

Example of what your test should look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeTestClass {

    private FooService service = new FooServiceImpl();

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void myTest() {    
       Foo fooWithXxxValueInBarColumn= new ...();
       em.persist(fooWithXxxValueInBarColumn);
       Foo newFooWithSameXxxValueInBarColumn = new ...();
       service.createFoo(newFooWithSameXxxValueInBarColumn); 
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to configure your test context to use a in-memory database and not your real database.